# smoothScrollToPosition does not scroll

Tags: android

I have a listfragment, whose listview is loaded using a cursorloader from the contacts provider. An onScrollListener is also registered.

**Requirement** :  The scroll listener is triggered whenever the user does a scroll through the UI. But i need to trigger it automatically when the listview is loaded for the first time as well.

**Problem** : I have tried using smoothScrollToPosition(0) in onActivityCreated() to trigger the scroll, but it does not scroll no matter what position i provide as parameter. Based on some other posts on SO,  I have tried using setSelection() instead, which does work, but does not trigger the scroll listener. I have tried the post method as well as below, but it makes no difference :

```
v.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                v.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
            }
        });
```

Any other way to trigger a scroll automatically?

Comment: Are you putting this in onLoadFinished? If you aren't, the data isn't there yet for you to scroll to.